# Function that only accepts enumeration types

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

*Man, I can't stand this damn templates no mo'*

So suppose I have this function...

```
void sort(vector<int>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

How can I make that function accept vectors of all enumeration types without overloading it 10 goddamn times?

I don't know much about templates but was thinking about doing something like this... (which gave me the error: type name is not allowed)

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>>>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just if you use fresh C++ (what I recommend if possible). There is a working example using concepts (c++20). Just tested at gcc 10

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T> requires std::is_enum<T>::value
void sort(std::vector<T> & vec)
{
        // stuff
}

int main()
{
        enum Mew
        {
            neat,
            ugly
        };

        std::vector<Mew> v;
        sort(v);               //works

        std::vector<int> v_int;
        sort(v_int);           //error here

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i use c++20 in msvc ?? cos i rlly want that requires word

Comment: I didn't check, but you can, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160 the feature is called "concepts", it's written it should work with /std:c++latest compiler flag (you can change c++ version in project settings)

Answer (score 0):

You were very close:

```
#include <vector>
    
template<typename T, typename =std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
enum x {};

void foo()
{
    std::vector<x> X;
    std::vector<int> Y;

    sort(X); // Works
    sort(Y); // ERROR
}
```

And with C++17 you can save a little bit of typing:

```
template<typename T, typename =std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>>
void sort(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: why sort(Y) wouldn't work?? isn't int an enum type??

Comment: `int` is not an enumerated type.

Comment: then im confused.. i thought is_enum didn't refer to the keyword enum, i thought it refered to enumerated types (all than can be sorted, such as int, double, float, unsigned int n all of those)

Comment: You were mistaken: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum -- "Checks whether T is an enumeration type", linking to the `enum` keyword. But if you want to also accept integral and floating point types, this is trivially adjusted, in the obvious way. This is what the `||` operator in C++ is for. Simply check for `is_integral` and `is_floating` point, with `||` liberally sprinkled between them.

Comment: so to make that function accept ints, doubles, floats... only way is overload??

Comment: Of course not. Like I pointed out, `||` is the way to go. `std::is_enum<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value ...` -- you can finish the reset of this yourself.

Comment: got it, and for like custom classes, i would have to use is_same right?.. someday.. someday i'll know all this stuff

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: prefer `std::enable_if_t<cond, int> = 0` over `typename = std::enable_if_t<cond>`. It allows overloads, cannot be hack jacked.

Comment: Pretty much, that's the story.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you have to use the value of `std::is_enum<T>`, not the class itself.

Second: take in count that `std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>` is `void` when `T` is an `enum`.

So, when `T` is an `enum` your function become

```
// ..................VVVV  void what ?
template<typename T, void>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

A possible solution could be add a `typename` on the left

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

Works, but there is a drawback: if you have to enable/disable only one version of `sort()`, all goes well. But if you want two different `sort()` functions (say one for enums and one for not-enums)

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value>>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<not std::is_enum<T>::value>>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

This doesn't works because you can't have two functions with the same signature (a default template type/value doesn't change the signature) and the SFINAE failure, removing only the default type for the second argument, doesn't disable the function but only doesn't permit that it match without expressing the second template parameter.

Solution for this problem: let SFINAE works on the left of the equal sign as follows

```
template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}

template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<not std::is_enum<T>::value, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
void sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

This way SFINAE enable/disable the functions so the two alternative function can works without interfere each others.

Another way (compatible with two alternative functions) is to use SFINAE to enable/disable the returned type, so

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<T>::value> sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<not std::is_enum<T>::value> sort(vector<T>& vec)
{
    // stuff
}
```

A couple of additional not requested suggestions:

1. doesn't name your classes and functions as classes/functions in the standard library; so give a different name to your `sort()` to avoid a collision with the standard `std::sort()`
2. avoid `using namespace std;`, or is really more probable a name collision (calling `sort()`, is called your `sort()` or `std::sort()` ?)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i got one more question.. where the hell did u learn all of this?? cos i wanna learn it too

Comment: @Karlos - Experience; a lot of experience. Stack overflow is very useful: I've learned a lot trying to respond to question like your question and reading other answers.